# Why move assignment operator should return reference to *this

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Can someone explain why the move assignment operator is (usually) declared as

```
Foo& operator=(Foo&&);
```

Why return a reference and not e.g. `Foo` or `Foo&&`? I understand why we want this for the regular assignment operator, due to associativeness rules as `(a=b)=c` being logically broken (although still compilable) if not returned by reference, but why is this the case when the RHS is a rvalue (xvalue/prvalue)?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. You can't return "the object itself" except by reference. If you mean "why not return a copy of the object", then that only works if the type is copyable, and even then copying might be more expensive than you'd like. `(a=b)=c` requires the first expression `(a=b)` to be an _lvalue_ whatever the argument type of the assignment operator, so you have to return a reference if you want to support that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I changed the question, why not just return `Foo`? or even `Foo&&`? What are the "chain" rules that will be broken?

Comment: Returning `Foo` is potentially expensive, and impossible if the type isn't copyable, as I said. Returning `Foo&&` is just weird; you don't want things mysteriously turning into _rvalues_ so that e.g. `f(a=b)` unexpectedly moves from `a` without you telling it to.

Comment: @MikeSeymour thanks, good point with this, you should post (if you want) an answer, as I don't think this issue is super obvious, although now it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Another way of looking at it.  If all you wanted was an rvalue and you were ok doing a copy, you could always do `Foo&& x = Foo(y);`  This would be the same in my mind as a move operator on y that does a copy so in that case the move operator would be redundant on top of the copy constructor.

Comment: @Pace, correct, I realized now that the copy idea was just plain stupid. Now also figured out why `Foo&&` as a return type is just not the way to go, so the only reasonable remaining return type is `Foo&`.

Comment: The duplicate is titled "copy assignment operator" but it should really read "copy/move assignment" as everything is the same

Comment: @MattMcNabb thanks for finding the dupe, I didn't jump into it... probably because I knew why it's OK for copying (so the title was misleading), but didn't really understand why it's OK for move.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning `Foo` is potentially expensive, and impossible if the type isn't copyable. It's also surprising: `(a=b)=c` would create a temporary and assign `c` to that, when you'd expect both assignments to be to `a`.

Returning `Foo&&` is just weird; you don't want things mysteriously turning into *rvalues* so that e.g. `f(a=b)` unexpectedly moves from `a` without you telling it to.

Returning `Foo&` is the conventional way to make the operator behave in an unsurprising way if you chain it.